# How to draw a pie with logarithmic scale in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, pie-chart, logarithm

I need to draw a pie (or a donut, or an half donut, I think that it's the same process) in Highcharts.
The problem is that the data are heavily biased, i.e. one slice has size = 3 and the second  one has size = 1000.

the final result is a pie with a giant slice and a slice almost invisible.

[image: my chart]

Is there a way to print the size of the slices in a logarithmic way (as for the axis charts)?

Comment: I don't see the use case for this. Pies and donuts are useful for showing relative percentages between data points in a set. If one data point is 2 orders of magnitude larger than the other one - well, that is the case and you should see it. If you have a "log" arc you would be deceiving the end user on the relative importance of one data point over another as it breaks the paradigm of how pie charts are usually viewed.

Comment: @wergeld I see your point and you're right, but I NEED to print all the series even if they has different order of magnitude

Comment: Interested to see what that would look like...

Comment: not so good, I know. The final donut will not represent the real "data" but, in the end, it's what I need :)

Comment: If you need to show numbers, but you are visualizing them in a manner that does not actually represent the numbers, at best all you've done is meaninglessly decorate the numbers, at worst you've completely mislead your audience.  Better to just display a simple list or table of numbers, where there is not a meaningless graphic to distort the data and confuse the consumers of the data. FWIW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pie chart does not use axis, so setting its type to logarithmic will not work. What you can do is transforming your data and preserving the "real" value so it can be displayed in a tooltip, data labels, etc.

```
    var data = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512],
        logData = data.map(function (value) {
        return {
            y: Math.log(value) / Math.LN10, 
            realY: value // store a pure value
          };
      });


    // later in chart options
    tooltip: {
     pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.realY}' // access the pure value in a tooltip
    }
```

Comparison pie charts with transformed data and with "pure" data: http://jsfiddle.net/rz9899j8/